# Range(variable).Value - - Loop

Tags: vba, excel

Can anybody help me with a simple question.

I try to apply filters to a pivot, such that I generate some values, after which I store them somewere else.

I need to iterate through cells C7 to C100, as each will create a set of different values.

I know how to refer to a specific cell in my code:

```
 CurrentPage = Range("C7").Value
```

How can I refer to column C, however the number "7" in the case above to be referend as a variable e.g

```
Dim j as Integer
j = 7

after loop
j = j+1
```

Comment: Cells(j,"C") within the loop

Comment: `Range("C" & j).Value` or `Cells(j,3).Value` or `Cells(j,"C").Value`. Take your pick.

Comment: Ahh great  `CurrentPage = Range("C" & j).Value` made the trick

Comment: `For Each c in Range("C7:C100").Cells: CurrentPage = c.Value: Next c`

Answer (score 1):

Something like (note that the For Loop increments j)

```
For j = 7 To 100
   Activesheet.Cells(j,"C") ......
Next j
```